# Query Mongo Collection of nested document of same type

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data

I have a not so unique requirement but i am just finding the right terminology to search, since i only keep getting results on how to query list/ array fields or nested elements.

Here is my class (document type)...

```
public class Item {
    private String identity     = null;
    private String name         = null;
    private String type         = null;
    private List<Item> grouping = null;
}
```

Thus, some entity instances of this `type` could get complex as shown below...

```
{
   "identity":"ITEM-1",
   "name":"Pack-1",
   "type":"Bundle",
   "grouping":[
      {
         "identity":"ITEM-2",
         "name":"Book",
         "type":"Atomic Unit"
      },
      {
         "identity":"ITEM-3",
         "name":"Stationary",
         "type":"Bundle",
         "grouping":[
            {
               "identity":"ITEM-4",
               "name":"Pen",
               "type":"Atomic Unit"
            },
            {
               "identity":"ITEM-5",
               "name":"Paper",
               "type":"Atomic Unit"
            },
            {
               "identity":"ITEM-6",
               "name":"Paraphernalia",
               "type":"Bundle",
               "grouping":[
                  {
                     "identity":"ITEM-7",
                     "name":"Eraser",
                     "type":"Atomic Unit"
                  },
                  {
                     "identity":"ITEM-8",
                     "name":"Ruler",
                     "type":"Atomic Unit"
                  },
                  {
                     "identity":"ITEM-9",
                     "name":"Compass",
                     "type":"Atomic Unit"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Now my requirement is to be able to search for `Book` or `Pen` or `Compass` and must be able to fetch the record `ITEM-1`. How do I achieve this in Mongo Query. I am using Spring Data Mongo Repository approach on my data abstraction service layer.

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

> my requirement is to be able to search for Book or Pen or Compass and
>   must be able to fetch the record ITEM-1.

You can try this query from `mongo` shell, and it fetches the document:

```
var SEARCH_ITEMS = [ "Book", "Pen", "Compass" ]
var ATOMIC = "Atomic Unit"

db.collection.find( {
  $or: [
    { "type": ATOMIC, name: { $in: SEARCH_ITEMS } },
    { "grouping.type": ATOMIC, "grouping.name": { $in: SEARCH_ITEMS } },
    { "grouping.grouping.type": ATOMIC, "grouping.grouping.name": { $in: SEARCH_ITEMS } },
    { "grouping.grouping.grouping.type": ATOMIC, "grouping.grouping.grouping.name": { $in: SEARCH_ITEMS } }
  ]
} )
```

Comment: Thank you @prasad_... the query requirement stems out of the polymorphic nature of entity instances that is now possible with hierarchical embedded document. To be clearer, the hierarchy chain can vary for every document in the collection. So I cannot assume the height of such lineage. Is there a more precise way to query `*.name` to ensure the semanic accuracy of the query?

Comment: Does the query work for the document you had posted?

Comment: Yes.. but i am really looking for a solution that will work for any height. The entity I posted is just for an example and every record will not be exactly like that. Some entities could be `Atomic Unit` at the top level and thus have no `grouping` at all. While others could have multiple `Bundle` inside `grouping` and may also have more than 5 levels of embedding.